# Fetching specific data from consumerfinance.gov into excel using VBA programming

Tags: socrata, soda

I want to fetch data from consumerfinance.gov and import it into an Excel spreadsheet. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try out our [OData API](http://dev.socrata.com/odata/), which would allow you to consume those datasets directly within Excel without needing to write any VBA at all?

*Edited:* All right, since it sounds like OData isn't an option, how about a [Web Query](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Get-external-data-from-a-Web-page-708f2249-9569-4ff9-a8a4-7ee5f1b1cfba)? You can us the CSV export (*Export* -> *Download* -> *CSV*) or the [CSV format from SODA](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/formats/csv.html) and I think that'd still work in 2007.

Comment: Thank you for your support!  Actually we are using office 2007, so there is no option for ODATA connection. I tried it in Tableau but was very slow as when we launch it data get started download. That's why I want to VBA to pull specific dataset. Plz help me out...

Comment: Edited my previous answer. I think Web Queries might be your solution.